forward all traffic to internal printer with wireguard
I setup an interface named "wgPrint" with wireguard with it's ip-address 10.0.0.30, and all traffic should be forwarded to my HP MFP printer to 192.168.0.11
wgPrint interface:
11: wgPrint: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state 
UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/none 
inet 10.0.0.30/32 scope global wgPrint
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

wg infos:
interface: wgPrint
public key: aGtJTLja+4xxEpEFbhCdAXKvDT0imeWn+kJOLPoOJB0=
private key: (hidden)
listening port: 51920

peer: iAl7D+t1YIPMbFHcCrylsu1M8VAXhKEwPzvv1Bi/Xw0=
endpoint: 192.168.0.30:51820
allowed ips: 10.0.0.2/32
latest handshake: 5 minutes, 45 seconds ago
transfer: 51.92 KiB received, 2.42 KiB sent

iptables-save:
-A INPUT -i wgPrint -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.0/24 -i wgPrint -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -i wgPrint -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.11
-A PREROUTING -i wgPrint -p udp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.11
-A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.11/32 -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.30
-A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.11/32 -p udp -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.30
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.30/32 -d 192.168.0.11/32 -o wgPrint -j MASQUERADE

What am I doing wrong that i still can't see the printer ?
for any help, thank you in advance.
Tamer

I solved it.
I added to the existing wireguard connection a 2nd ip-Address, and removed the "wgPrint" device.
now it looks like this:
6: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/none 
inet 10.0.0.1/24 scope global wg0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 10.0.0.30/32 scope global wg0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

and the iptables rules are following:
-A INPUT -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.30/32 -i wg0 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.11
-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.30/32 -i wg0 -p udp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.11
-A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.11/32 -o br0 -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.30
-A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.11/32 -o br0 -p udp -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.30  

I am using on android "mopria scan" and "mopria print"
discovery automatically does not work, but adding the device address 192.168.0.11 showed me the scanner and printer.
to be tripple sure i setup wireguard VPN to block all connections that are not going through VPN.
